# Error - Main Class not found

Tags: java

Can't seem to figure out why this simple program has stopped working on my computer.  My programs that I compiled up until a Windows update are fine but when I try to compile a new program I get the following.  I've attached a picture of the program and the command prompt error message.  I've checked the CLASSPATH and it looks fine.

Program - HelloWorldApp.java

```
class HelloWorldApp{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); //Display the string
   }
}
```

execute javac HelloWorldApp.java - all is fine

execute java HelloWorldApp -

> Error:  Main method not found in class HelloWorldApp, please define
>   the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX
>   application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Please excuse me if this has been answered.  I searched but couldn't find this problem

[image: image of notepad program and execution in command prompt]

Comment: Can you do a `dir` at the command prompt to show what files are in that directory?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the point, but your class HelloWorldApp isn't declared as public. If you don't mind, it would be interesting to try changing this and testing again.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida that shouldn't matter. We should be able to invoke main method also from non-public classes.

Comment: @Pshemo Agreed. As I said, I wasn't sure about it. Just a try when nobody seems to work. But you are right, I've just checked documentation and this is not necessary. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: sorry "Bill the Lizard" this program works fine on my computer.  It is a friends program and on his computer that is having the problems  Adding public to the class does not help.

Comment: I've asked him to send me a screen shot.  I think you are on to something!!!!!!!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Java?

Comment: As I wrote below.  He created a String.java program and class.  I'm sure "Bill the Lizard" was on to it!  Thanks to all!

Comment: @pp_ I had no idea that when you flag a question one of the options is "simple typographical error". Thanks - I'll know it for next time!

Answer (score 3):

Have you declared a `String` class among your list of classes? If so, try using `java.lang.String[] args` as argument to your main method.

Comment: Thanks Sriniketh.  I've asked for a screen shot from my friend and hoping you have uncovered the problem (didn't even think of that!)

Comment: @stjava So how did it go?

Comment: Sriniketh wins.  He had created a String.java program and class.  I didn't think about that as a possibility so thanks to all!!!!!!

Comment: @stjava Also tell your friend to never name his class (or other type) with names which are already in use by Java, like `Object` or most common cause of this kind of problems: `Character`.